# Return null When Using DropDownList

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I want to add news in database. When I use this code for Select Category return

Me Null . How can I resolve this?

```
<select name="category">
    @{
        foreach (var item in RCat.MainCategory().Where(a=>a.ParentID==1))
        {
            <option value="@item.ID">@item.Title</option>
        }
    }

</select>
```

My Controller :

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult CreateNews(Tbl_News t, HttpPostedFileBase pic, int Category)
{
    try
    {
        if (Session["Username"] == null)
            return RedirectToAction("Register", "Home");
        if (pic == null)
        {
            ViewBag.Style = "color:red";
            ViewBag.Message = "خطایی رخ داده . باید عکسی را برای خبر انتخاب کنید";
            return View();
        }
        if (Category == 0)
        {
            ViewBag.Style = "color:red";
            ViewBag.Message = "خطایی رخ داده . باید یکی از دسته ها را انتخاب کنید";
            return View();
        }
        t.Date = DateTime.Now.Date;
        t.Dislike = 0;
        t.Like = 0;
        t.Visit = 0;
        t.Username = Session["Username"].ToString();
        if (t.Type != "iran" && t.Type != "world" && t.Type != "sport" && t.Type != "art" && t.Type != "knowledge" && t.Type != "economic" && t.Type != "memo" && t.Type != "you" && t.Type != "pic" && t.Type != "video")
            t.Type = null;


        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (pic != null)
            {
                if (pic.ContentLength <= 512000)
                {
                    if (pic.ContentType == "image/jpeg")
                    {
                        Random rnd = new Random();
                        string picname = rnd.Next().ToString();
                        string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/img/NewsPic/"));
                        pic.SaveAs(path + picname);
                        t.Image = picname;
                        db.Tbl_News.Add(t);
                        if (Convert.ToBoolean(db.SaveChanges()))
                        {
                            var q = (from a in db.Tbl_News
                                     orderby a.Date descending
                                     select a).FirstOrDefault();
                            Tbl_Cat_News TCN = new Tbl_Cat_News();
                            TCN.NewsID = q.ID;
                            TCN.CatID = Category;
                            db.Tbl_Cat_News.Add(TCN);
                            if (Convert.ToBoolean(db.SaveChanges()))
                            {
                                ViewBag.Style = "color:green";
                                ViewBag.Message = "با موفقیت ثبت شد";
                                return View();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                ViewBag.Style = "color:red";
                                ViewBag.Message = "خطایی رخ داده . خبر ثبت نشد";
                                return View();
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ViewBag.Style = "color:red";
                            ViewBag.Message = "خطایی رخ داده . خبر ثبت نشد";
                            return View();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ViewBag.Style = "color:red";
                        ViewBag.Message = "خطایی رخ داده . فرمت تصویر باید jpg باشد";
                        return View();
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    ViewBag.Style = "color:red";
                    ViewBag.Message = "خطایی رخ داده . حجم تصویر باید بیشتر کمتر از 515 کیلو بایت باشد";
                    return View();
                }
            }

            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Logout", "Admin");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.Style = "color:red";
            ViewBag.Message = "خطایی رخ داده . تمامی فیلدها باید پر شوند";
            return View();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

        return Content("خطا");
    }
}
```

Comment: Where in your view do you bind anything to `Type`? (all you have shown is a `<select>` with `name="Category"`

Comment: no . i not bind any thing . how bind for this code ?

Comment: You have not shown you models so I cant guess. And use `@Html.DropDownListFor()` to generate a `<select>` (not that awful loop)

Comment: This My Controller  . Please Help Me

Answer (score 0):

You have all **OR** condition, so if **any type not match** with **any condition** it fires "t.Type = null;" and because of that you always get "NULL" value.